# Create a meta-package in CentOS 8

Tags: linux, centos

I’m trying to create a meta-package in CentOS 8 that installs vim and nano.

I built rpm-package via spec file.
The spec file:

```
Summary: It's just a test meta_package
Version: 0.1 
Release: 1
Group: Applications/Internet
License: GPL 
BuildArch: noarch
Requires: nano, vim

%description
A test meta_package.

%prep 

%build

%install

%clean

%post
yum install -y nano
yum install -y vim

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)

%changelog
```

Building

```
rpmbuild --bb meta_package.spec
```

Then I launch it like

```
rpm -I meta_package-0.1-1.noarch.rpm
```

But packages haven’t been installed. Is there any possible solution to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For meta-packages, you must *not* specify dependencies in the `%post` section.

You simply specify them with `Requires:` tag. Example:

```
Requires: nano
Requires: vim-enhanced
```

Then use a package manager like `yum` or `dnf` to satisfy dependencies at install time.

Comment: Pretty sure this advice applies to all packages, not just meta-packages! Dependencies need to be in `Requires` (or `Recommends` in newer versions) .